# Can you move/copy a multipart 7z file while it still is compressing?

Tags: ftp, 7-zip, file-transfer

If you are compressing a 7zip archive and creating split archive, do you need to wait for the entire compression process to complete before you start copying the completed pieces out of the folder?

I was wondering because frequently I am zipping several gig files and needing to ftp them, it would be useful if I could start the ftp transfer of the .001 piece while .002 was being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the file is written, it will not again be touched - I am not 100% about the first/original file as I have never tried to do this, but I am certain that other parts would be ok.

Comment: the 001 file is the one I was concerned about too.

Answer (score 0):

Having done this now, I can tell you that YES, the .001 file is modified at the end of the compression.  The 002 and later files are not modified but their last modified date is updated.